# how to create a rectangle of asterik using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am beginner in matlab. can anybody tell how to create a rectangle of asterik as in the image:

[image]

Comment: Use this code golf post as inspiration.  Simply replace the hash signs with asterisks.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57845/surround-a-string-with-hashes/57887#57887

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way without loops:

```
m = 5;     %// number of rows
n = 12;    %// number of cols
c = ' ';   %// inner character
C = '*';   %// outer character
x = repmat(c, m, n);   %// create m x n array of c
x([1 end], :) = C;     %// replace top and bottom with C
x(:, [1 end]) = C;     %// replace left and right with C
```

This gives

```
>> disp(x)
************
*          *
*          *
*          *
************
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%symbol to print
symbol = '*';

%How many Rows in your rectangle
numRows = 20;
%How many columns in your rectangle
numColumns = 10;

%loop through each row
for currentRow = 1 : numRows
    %loop thourgh each column
    for currentColumn = 1 : numColumns
        %if we are in the first or last row print a symbol
        if(currentRow == 1 || currentRow == numRows)
            fprintf('%s',symbol)
        %if we are in the first or last column print a symbol
        elseif(currentColumn == 1 || currentColumn == numColumns)
            fprintf('%s',symbol)
        %otherwise print a blank space (file the middle)
        else
            fprintf(' ')
        end
    end
    %at the end of the column move to the next line
    fprintf('\n');
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that the only reason I'm posting this answer (Rob F.'s answer will work just fine) is because it gives me a chance to use a MATLAB function that I don't get to use very often: [blanks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blanks.html).

Here we go:

```
row_count = 5;   %// number of rows we want
col_count = 17;  %// number of columns
A = '';          %// our starting (blank) char array
                 %// note that growing arrays like this is sloooow
                 %// but for our purposes, it should be fine

for row = 1:row_count
   A(row,:) = blanks(col_count);   %// make each row a row of blanks
end

%// now add the asterisks using row and column indices
A(1,:) = '*';           %// top row
A(row_count,:) = '*';   %// or `A(end,:)` - bottom row
A(:,1) = '*';           %// left column
A(:,col_count) = '*';   %// or `A(:,end)` - right column

disp(A);
```

Result:

```
*****************
*               *
*               *
*               *
*****************
```

Comment: `blanks`! Good idea! I don't use it often either

Comment: @LuisMendo Unfortunately, its usefulness is limited because it only creates one-dimensional arrays. If you need more dimensions, you either have to use `reshape`, or loop like I did.

Comment: This would make a good [code golf question](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=NDJpaVgiMzIsOEx0SyQoYw&input=NQoxMg) :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Very similar to the one rayryeng linked above, though.

Comment: I'm tempted to go edit my code golf solution for that challenge I posted above.  I have wasted bytes because I was trying to create an array of `blank`s :)